# PyQt and Postgresql: syntax error on simple query which works in PSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt, pyqt5

I am sure it is very simple but I cannot get this basic query to work using PyQt5 using QPSQL.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import *

class Main():

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        SQL = "SELECT address FROM organisation_addresses WHERE organisation_id = ?"
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare(SQL)
        query.addBindValue(12)       
        query.exec_(SQL)
        query.first()

        if query.isActive():
                print(query.value("address"))
        else:
            print(query.lastError().text())

if __name__=="__main__":
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName(server)
    db.setDatabaseName(database)
    db.setUserName(user)
    db.setPassword(pword)
    if (db.open()==False):
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error", db.lastError().text())

    myapp = Main()
```

If I change the query to "SELECT address FROM organisation_addresses WHERE organisation_id = 85" comment out query.prepare and query.addBindValue, the query works fine.  It seems to dislike my "?".
When I run the query in psql, it also runs correctly.

When I run select version() on Postgres, I get:

```
PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit
```

I have tried the query in PyQt on Linux Mint 19.3, Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.  Same result.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is this ```query.exec_(SQL)``` correct? Shouldn't it be ```query.exec(SQL)```? Have you tried the other variations from here?: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the placeholder then you should not pass the query to exec() since QSqlQuery already has the statement,only use:

```
SQL = "SELECT address FROM organisation_addresses WHERE organisation_id = ?"
query = QSqlQuery()
query.prepare(SQL)
query.addBindValue(12)       
query.exec_()
query.first()

if query.isActive():
    print(query.value("address"))
else:
    print(query.lastError().text())
```

Comment: Sometimes the trees obscure the forest. Thanks!